# My postfix email server can send email using forge domain name via outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, postfix

I setup a Postfix mail server in our office and we are using MS-outlook for mail-client.

I can finally send and receive email via outlook.. but my problem now is that i can send

email using different domain via outlook.  How can i prevent it?????

How can i configure postfix to send email using "mydomain.com" only and prevent it to send email using  "fakedomain.com".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the "check_sender_access" directive - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-blacklist-reject-sender-email-address/

Comment: Hi thanks you for the reply, but is it possible to just deny all-domain at sender_access list and allow only my-domain..???  i already read that link but its good for one email address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders, reject

Then create /etc/postfix/restricted_senders
domain.name          OK

(In fairness, I've not tried this.  I'm not convinced there are many cases for the solution.  I'd rather do SMTP auth, and add a header showing who the authenticated user was that sent the email)

Answer (score 0):

what is the OS on which postfix is installed, what is your setting in main.cf and what authentication method you are using for example SASL.

If you can provide all the details it will be easier to answer as to what you are missing.